# HTTP security headers on non HTML (images, JavaScript, etc)

Tags: tls, http, xss, html, hsts

Let's say, the HTTP security headers below are applied to all HTML pages of a site:

- HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)
- X-Frame-Options (XFO)
- X-XSS-Protection
- X-Content-Type-Options

Is it OK to **not** put those HTTP security headers on non HTML resources (images, JavaScript files, etc) but those headers are applied to all HTML resources.

Any security risks for that?

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If the website accepts user-submitted content, it's best to keep the XSS and nosniff headers on, in case they provide a loophole.

Lack of HSTS is also fine; however ensure that you have your cookies separated from HTTP and HTTPS, just in case.